# Concatenate part of the string from one column to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Here's what my excel sheet looks like (sample data)

| ID | English | French | Expected French Column Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Dog";"Type:Animal" | "Chien" | "Chien";"Type:Animal" |
| 2 | "Eagle";"Type:Bird" | "Aigle" | "Aigle";"Type:Bird" |

So what I want to do is, copy part of the English string (Type:***) to the French column. Doing it manually is not an option because I have 100s of products, I want to find the substring, which is enclosed in double quotes ("Type:") and add it to the French String.

Edit: Apologies my question is not formatted properly. I have attached a picture to show what my excel sheet looks like.

[image: excel sheet example]

Comment: `=CONCAT(C1, ";", MID(B1, SEARCH(";", B1)+1, 20))`. I have assumed the length to be of 20 which you may adjust dynamically using LEN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=C2&";"&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,";",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

[image]